# how to store xpath count and increment it using selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

```
<td class="datepickerSelected">   
<a href="#">   
<span>21</span>   
</a>   
</td>  
 <td class="">   
<a href="#">
```

How to get csscount/xpath count in a variable and increment the count to point the next location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use storeXpathCount command to store count in variable. (Ref : http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.in/2013/06/using-storexpathcount-in-selenium-ide.html) and then use store command with string like javascript{storedVars.MyVar++;} to increment value of variable. (Ref : http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.in/2013/07/steps-for-data-driven-testing-with.html)

Comment: While the links may answer the question, it is better to post the essential parts of it here also. Doing so would make sure that your answer remains valid even if the links become inactive.

Comment: StoreXpathcount //div[@class='datepicker']/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody[2]/tr/td[@class='' or @class='datepickerSaturday' or @class='datepickerSunday']   count.                                                                I used the above code to get the total number of links matching the format.

Comment: I couldnot execute the above case. But I found a solution to my problem. I stored the current date in a variable. I booked all the slots for the current date.Then I incremented the date value to book appointments for the next date. Using while loop I checked for the condition whether the date is less than or equal to 31. At the end of the loop, I incremented the date value. So I can book appointments for the entire month starting from the current date. Thanks for your help.